# Need help understanding what's going on in my while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

My program executes just fine, but I have questions about how my `while` loop is set up.

I know the Boolean values for true and false are 1 and 0, respectively, but I'm not understanding why my output displays the even and odd numbers backwards (to my understanding, it's backwards). Simply put, I don't understand why `if ( number % 2 == 0 )` would display that a number is even and when I change it to 1, it displays odd. I'm reading this line as, if (even number equals to false). I don't know if that's where I'm going wrong. What's the correct way to read this line?

The way I have my code set up now displays the numbers correctly, I'm just not understanding why. Can anyone help?

```
// Program indefinitely displays an even
// or odd number until a negative number
// is entered.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    while ( number >= 0 )
    {
        if ( number % 2 == 0 )
        {
            cout << number << " is even \n";
            cout << "Please enter a number: ";
            cin >> number;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << number << " is odd \n";
            cout << "Please enter a number: ";
            cin >> number;
        }
    }

    cout << "Thank you. \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You created an account on SO to ask why a number which is divisible by 2 even?

Comment: I don't think it's too bad. Testing for evenness is surprisingly non-trivial. I once fixed a bug due to `if ( number % 2 == 1 )` in the small hours and the code was written by an experienced chap who should have known better.

Comment: @user3286661 Sue me for being a complete newbie and not catching a simple mistake. As I replied to an actual helpful person, I was reading `0` as false and not the entire expression as `0 == 0`.

Comment: @Alexa: rap on the knuckles for not writing `0 == 0`.

Comment: I bet you that "actual helpul person" didn't know earlier that you were reading 0 as false and not the entire expression as 0==0.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah, yes. That slips through from time to time and I only catch it when there's an error when running.

Answer (score 0):

`number % 2` is `0` if `number` divides `2` (i.e. is *even*), `1` if `number` is *positive* and does not divide `2` (i.e. is *odd*), and `-1` if `number` is *negative* and does not divide `2` (i.e. is *odd*). (The last point must be the case from C++11 onwards).

So, since `0 == 0` is `true`, `number % 2 == 0` is `true` if, and only if, `number` is *even*.

So you've written `if ( number % 2 == 0 )` to trap all even cases, and the `else` traps the odd cases.

Testing  `if ( number % 2 == 1 )` is only a test for positive oddness, but older C++ standards allow this to be `true` for negative `number`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see completely. I was reading `0` as false and not as the remainder of an even number, which is `0`, equaling to `0`. Thank you so much. Can't believe it was something that simple that was tripping me up.

Comment: I don't regard it as being simple. The `%` has only been locked down fully since C++11.